# How to get point coordinates in chart.js scatter plot?

Tags: javascript, plot, chart.js, react-chartjs

I'm trying to fetch x- and y- coordinates from a chart.js scatter plot through a mouse click event in a react application.
Following this tutorial: https://react-chartjs-2.js.org/docs/working-with-events
I implemented a call-back for the mouse click:

```
  function scatter_point_selector(event)
  {
    var element = getElementAtEvent(scatter_ref.current, event);
    var element_ix = getElementAtEvent(scatter_ref.current, event)[0].index;
    var dataset = getDatasetAtEvent(scatter_ref.current, event);

    console.log('element = ', element);
```

from which I see the data structure with the `x` and `y` coordinates in the browser console:

[image]

The problem is that the x- and y-coordinates of the data points are at x=-100, -95, ..., 50 and at y=0, 180. These are not the same as the x- and y- listed in the element.

How can I fetch the x- and y-coordinates of the data points when clicking on them?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scatter_ref.current.scales.x.getValueForPixel(xValue)` and `scatter_ref.current.scales.y.getValueForPixel(yValue)` to get the values you see on the axis